# how to play audio even when silent/mute switch is on in Ionic 3?

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using [Ionic audio](http://arielfaur.github.io/ionic-audio/2.0/index.html) plugin for my player. When the silent/mute switch is on in ios I couldn't hear audio which I feel is unusual cuz other music apps are playing audios in the same case. Is there a way I can fix this? I tried googling it, unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for Ionic. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @gowtham ! Did you find something interesting about that? For a POC I have to force audio even if sound is muted on the device. If you have any update on this I'll appreciate to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Audio or Ionic Native Audio plugin, use the media plugin. It will play audio while in silent mode.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media

```
const file: MediaObject = this.media.create('assets/audio/audio.wav');
file.play();
```